# When is it more efficient to put a PC to sleep rather than shut it down?

Tags: sleep, shutdown

I have a second PC in my office that I only use about once every 48 hours, for a few hours. I've read that one of the most stressful and life-shortening acts you can commit against your machine is shutting it down and booting it back up often. However, my understanding is that this is primarily because of HDDs, which have moving parts.

In today's world, where a lot of higher-end machines have SSDs, is it more efficient for me to just keep my PC in sleep mode rather than shutting it down and booting it back up several times per week?

Comment: efficient based on what considerations? time, power use, ease-of-management, etc?

Comment: Perhaps it was true that restarting a vacuum-tube computer with mercury delay-line RAM would shorten it's life, but it's certainly *not* true today, particularly with SSD's. The ancient and honorable PC on which this is written has HDD, and for ~11 years, has been hibernated (power *completely* off) or shut down fully with nary a hiccough (it's so old, I must use an ancient spelling for that condition!).

Answer (score 0):

> I've read that one of the most stressful and life-shortening acts you can commit against your machine is shutting it down and booting it back up often. However, my understanding is that this is primarily because of HDDs, which have moving parts.

In practice – no, not nearly as much as you imagine.

Regular read/write operations of an HDD can practically be ignored; asking the HDD to read your entire OS doesn't really hurt it by any measurable amount.

The power-on process of the HDD itself (i.e. spinning up an HDD that's been powered off) might wear it mechanically a little bit more, but a modern HDD would be rated for some 10,000 to 50,000 start/stop cycles before it's supposed to reach "risk of failure". (I pulled the number [out of Google](https://www.toshiba-storage.com/es/trends-technology/mttf-what-hard-drive-reliability-really-means/).)

...So because it's a *mostly* harmless operation, it is not actually limited to boot and shutdown anymore – if you were assuming that the HDD only has to start spinning when the PC is turned on, no, that's not the case nowadays. The OS can and will ask the HDD to spin down when it's been idle and then will spin it up again when needed. (Laptops *aggressively* spin down their HDDs to save power, and they still last decades.)

And, of course, the exact same thing happens when you put the PC to sleep: all HDDs are spun down, unloaded, and powered off, and then powered back on again when you wake the PC up. The only difference is whether the PC's RAM stays powered on or not.

> In today's world, where a lot of higher-end machines have SSDs, is it more efficient for me to just keep my PC in sleep mode rather than shutting it down and booting it back up several times per week?

It can be more efficient to keep it in sleep mode *regardless* of what kind of storage it has. (Maybe even more efficient if it has an HDD, considering the boot time.)

You'll have to calculate whether it costs you more in terms of electricity consumption and in terms of productivity to keep the PC asleep for instant wake-up or to wait for it to boot up every time you need it; but you can pretty much ignore the "computer life-shortening" part of it.

For a *very* rarely used PC (e.g. once a week), I'd go with the "hibernate" mode in Windows; it always resumes from disk, so it's slower than "sleep" mode (which already has everything in RAM), but since it's a linear read as opposed to many scattered reads it's still much faster than a regular boot process. But in your case, I wouldn't go so far as to definitely recommend it; the default "hybrid sleep" mode has its own advantages.

(By default, Windows has "hybrid sleep" enabled which stores the hibernation snapshot but then proceeds to sleep with RAM powered on, which is still just the regular "sleep" mode with added safety against power outages.)

Answer (score 0):

For long periods of inactivity, shutdown wins on every aspect
except one : Sleep mode is better if
you’ll need the computer again in a short time, since all your apps
will be available almost immediately when you wake it up,
without having to restart everything.

Shutdown is better on :

- Power efficiency : Sleep still takes up some power for keeping
  some components powered on such as the RAM
- Safety : While shut down the computer is not vulnerable to power cuts,
  surges and lightning
- Lifetime : The computer's lifetime is longer when not under power
- Function : Windows should be restarted from time to time, as keeping
  it on for too long may cause it to slow down, so re-initialization
  periodically is a good thing. Startup places a bit of a stress on
  the components which may detect failures earlier.

Hibernation may offer the best of both worlds : Economical on power
and quick to bring up your last environment without the need
to restart your apps.

Comment: Reboots are still essential even for shutdowns because of hybrid shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

In modern versions of windows, consider using hibernation rather than sleep to have the best of both worlds.

Let me explain.

With modern versions of windows, this is version 8 and up, you have a feature called Hybrid shutdown.

This is enabled by default.

What Hybrid shutdown does is the following: When you press start, shutdown, shutdown; windows will log you out and then puts your computer in hibernation.
While in this state, any form of wake up events are disabled though.

After you turn your computer on using the powerbutton, it will resume from hibernation and you get the logon screen again. If you have only one user with no password, or auto-login enabled, it will then automatically log you in.

Your programs start up again like normal, and after a bit of waiting, you can use your computer again.

Because hibernation was used instead of fully turning off your computer, drivers are kept in memory, and part of the startup delay is removed.

Now, lets compare this to using hibernation instead:

When you press start, shutdown, hibernate; windows will immediately, in its current state, place the computer in hibernation. The content of memory is written to disk first, but the entire process is still very fast.

When you now resume the computer, you instantly resume from where you left off, with all your programs still running, ready to resume work instantly.

When using hibernation, one of the challenges become that your computer may automatically turn on by itself.

This can be changed by altering settings in Power Management, and if done properly, you effectively create the same experience for turning off the computer vs hibernation, with the exception that you can use your computer so much faster.

Sleep will be even faster, but the downside with sleep is that (where it is also capable of waking up by remote events), it will consume more power as it will keep all the stuff in memory and that means the computer needs to keep supplying the memory with electricity. It is not much.

I, myself, switched to using hibernation years ago now. I do it at home and at work since early in windows 10, after I fully understood that hybrid shutdown is basically using hibernation.

Having all your programs ready, and no startup delay because all your programs are closed and need to open again, easily gives you 10 minutes a day of extra work time, and even more if your computer is older and slower. This also allows you to turn it off quicker (by this I mean, if you know you can resume fast, you are more tempted to place the computer in hibernation, than to just keep it on).

In the past, I used to keep my computer running with the monitors turned off because it took too much time to start things up, or I had some programs running that I did not want to close. Now, I can just hibernate and continue. Going away for an hour? Hibernating the computer.

One note though, when you either use sleep or hibernation, your computer is not rebooting. This may cause it that Windows Updates are being run less frequently. Don't get into the habit of not installing Windows Updates and not reboot.

Microsoft went to Hybrid Shutdown with the idea that your computer will still reboot every once in a while for windows updates. Rebooting your system is essential because that will restart your drivers.

Keeping a computer running for a long time without rebooting, ever, can create weird problems that are often the result of a driver crashing in the background, leading to new problems where eventually you experiencing a problem, as it becomes visible to you, while this problem has an inheritage of a different problem that you cannot see due to a problem with a driver.

So if you go the sleep/hibernation way, if you have a weird issue with your computer, just always reboot as first step, just in case, especially if it has been weeks ago since your previous reboot.